# Form disappear in vb.net after closing previous form

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB program.
Working with VS2022.
The prog. start with Form2 that call to Form1.
When Form1 is shown I want Form2 to be close.
I do this code :

```
  Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Form2.Close()
        Me.Visible = True
  End Sub
```

I also set the project to shut down when the last form is closed.
However when Form1 is shown I can't see it and the compiler is still running.
I tried to add a timer that close Form2 after I can see that Form1 is loaded , but ,again, Form1 is going to unvisible mode.
I verify with the debugger that there is no additional code after the  Form1_Shown sub
Why is that?

Comment: What framework are you targeting? Particularly these days, that's important information to provide because things are changing fast in many areas and the difference between .NET Framework and .NET Core can be significant.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Create a new test project with the minimum code possible to demonstrate your issue and then show us ALL that code.

Comment: You will see from my answer below that things work as you expect in .NET Framework projects but not in .NET Core projects. This is a perfect example of why it's important to AKWAYS specify what framework you're targeting. Often times, things are the same between versions but, when they're not, it can save everyone some time if we know what version to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

TL:DR:

Don't change the startup object for the project, i.e. leave it set to the default `Sub Main` and manually change the `MainForm` to the desired type in the `MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm` method.

Full explanation:

I have tested what you describe targeting .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 5 & 7. The first test worked exactly as you expect but the last two do not. This is due to an issue with the way that the VB Application Framework has been implemented for .NET Core (.NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core). Note that all that stuff had to be rebuilt from the ground up, so there are some things different or missing when compared to .NET Framework. Some may be by design and some may be oversights. There is a workaround to this issue though.

When targeting .NET Framework with the Application Framework enabled, there is a field named *Startup form* and you can only select a form. `Sub Main` is not an option.

[image]

If you disable the Application Framework, the field becomes *Startup object* and `Sub Main` is included in the list.

[image]

When targeting .NET Core, whether the Application Framework is enabled or not, the corresponding field is named *Startup object* and `Sub Main` is in the list, selected by default:

[image]

If you select a form from the list in that field, it will actually bypass the Application Framework. You can see that because a `Button` on your form will look like its from Windows 2000 as it will not have visual styles applied, which is done in that method:

[image]

For this reason, the shutdown mode you selected is also ignored. This is where the Application Framework does its magic, in the Application.Designer.vb file:

```vb
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On


Namespace My

    'NOTE: This file is auto-generated; do not modify it directly.  To make changes,
    ' or if you encounter build errors in this file, go to the Project Designer
    ' (go to Project Properties or double-click the My Project node in
    ' Solution Explorer), and make changes on the Application tab.
    '
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
            Me.IsSingleInstance = False
            Me.EnableVisualStyles = True
            Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = True
            Me.ShutdownStyle = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterAllFormsClose
            Me.HighDpiMode = HighDpiMode.DpiUnaware
        End Sub

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.WinFormsApp3.Form1
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Note that the shutdown mode has been changed from the default but the main form is still showing a `Form1`, despite the startup object being changed to `Form2`. All this code is completely ignored by changing the startup object.

The solution is to NOT change the startup object, i.e. leave it set to `Sub Main`, which is the default, but make a manual change to that `OnCreateMainForm` method instead. It's not ideal to modify such auto-generated files but it's required in this case. Manually change `Form1` to `Form2` in that method. Note that the file is not displayed in the Solution Explorer by default, so you'll have to click the *Show All Files* button and then expand nodes under *My Project* until you find it. Once that change is made, you're good to go.

Note that it is pointless to set `Visible` to `True` in a form's `Shown` event handler because it is already visible at that point. You simply need `Form1.Show()` in `Form2` and `Form2.Close()` in `Form1`.

Answer (score -1):

This is intentional design. The startup object (in your case, Form2) needs to stay loaded for the lifetime of your app.

I would recommend hiding Form2 instead of trying to unload it. Then put some code in Form1 so when it is closed, it shows Form2 again:

```
Public Class Form2
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form1.Show()
    Me.Hide()
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Form1_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
    Form2.Show()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: *"The startup object (in your case, Form2) needs to stay loaded for the lifetime of your app"*. That's not true. If you set the Shutdown Mode to "last form" rather than "main form", you can close the main form as long as you have opened at least one other form first. the OP said that they have done that and the code closes `Form2` when `Form1` has been shown so, in theory, there should be no issue.